# How can you find and click an image on a webpage?

Tags: image, search, click, mouse, move

I'm trying to find a button on a webpage and click it. Here's a script I tried to make for this:

IfWinExist, Google - Mozilla Firefox
WinActivate
ImageSearch, Foundx, Foundy, 18, 69, 371, 328, C:\users\bob\desktop\google.png
if ErrorLevel
    MsgBox, Image not found.
else,
MouseMove

This isn't my actual script obviously, but it's the same commands. I want a script to locate an image on a page, move the mouse to the center of the image, and click. My problem with my script is that I can't save the coordinates of the found image and move the mouse to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to establish whether the search form makes a POST or GET request.  A GET request means that values are passed in the querystring.  You can see this with Google.  All you need to do is formulate your own querystring to include the search word and make an HttpWebRequest using that.  If it is a POST request, you need to make a slightly different type of HttpWebRequest. which passes values in the Form collection rather than the QueryString.

Here's an article that makes basic use of the GET request: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/49/How-to-read-a-remote-web-page-with-ASP.NET-2.0.  A method ofr the Form request is below:

```
public static string HttpPostRequest(string url, string post)
 {
   var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
   byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(post);
   WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
   request.Method = "POST";
   request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
   request.ContentLength = data.Length;
   Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
   stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
   stream.Close();
   WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
   String result;
   using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
   {
     result = sr.ReadToEnd();
     sr.Close();
   }
   return result;
 }
```

answer from "Mikesdotnetting"
in : http://forums.asp.net/t/1495798.aspx/1